# add record for every single id when join table

Tags: mysql, join

I need help with query

let say i have 2 tables

```
tableA
------------------------------------------
id  | name
1   | ABC
2   | DEF
3   | GHI

tableB
------------------------------------------
id  | anotherID  | Amount
1   | 1          | 1000
2   | 1          | 2000 
3   | 1          | 3000
1   | 2          | 4000
2   | 2          | 5000
1   | 3          | 6000
```

i need this list

```
jointable
------------------------------------------
id  | anotherID  | Amount
1   | 1          | 1000
2   | 1          | 2000 
3   | 1          | 3000
1   | 2          | 4000
2   | 2          | 5000
3   | 2          | 0
1   | 3          | 6000
2   | 3          | 0
3   | 3          | 0
```

i need every single id have value even its 0 for every single anotherID value..

example : 
tableA have 3 id & distinct anotherID tableB have 3 records so i will need 3 * 3 = 9 records..

how to do this with query?? i can do with left join and union but i want to know if there some more effective way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b863b/13)

```
select T1.ID,T2.AnotherId,
       COALESCE(T3.Amount,0) as Amount
FROM TableA as T1
CROSS JOIN (Select distinct anotherID FROM TableB) as T2

LEFT JOIN TableB as T3 on (T1.id=T3.id) 
                          AND 
                          (T2.anotherID=T3.anotherID)

Order by T2.anotherId,T1.Id
```